How to continue list numbering via office.js?
I'm implementing Word add-in with office.js and I need to generate this list:
1. Section 1
2. Section 2
2.1 Section 2.1
Text
Yet another text 
with line breaks
2.2 Section 2.2
Another text
3. Section 3

Not programmatically I implement this as "continue numbering" while adding next paragraph.
I've tried:

Adding separate list for each section. This solves problem with numbering, but it's wrong when you try to add some section afterwards: numbering is obviously not updated for lists below.
Adding paragraphs "After" list. This adds numbered paragraphs first and then all other paragraphs "after".

1. Section 1
2. Section 2
2.1 Section 2.1
2.2 Section 2.2
3. Section 3
Text
Yet another text 
with line breaks
Another text


Detaching paragraphs. The same as above: numbered first and all other paragraphs "after".
Attaching only needed paragraphs to one list. This throws an error after trying to attach paragraph after first non-list paragraph.

PS. I'm testing in web Word.
